# Post List<model> to MVC web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to `POST` to `List<model>` but the model is always empty (`null`).

**ApiController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddShop(List<Shop> shop)
{

}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Shop 
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I am posting as `Json` with postman:

```
    {
      {
       "Name"  : "Shop1", 
       "Email" : "shop1@email.com"    
       },
       {
       "Name"  : "Shop2", 
       "Email" : "shop2@email.com"    
       }    
    }
```

When I'm posting to the same model but not as a `List<model>` it's successfully binded:

**ApiController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddShop(Shop shop)
{

}
```

**Postman:**

```
{
     "Name"  : "Shop1", 
     "Email" : "shop1@email.com"    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be array in your case, your Json should look like this:

```
[
   {
     "Name"  : "Shop1", 
     "Email" : "shop1@email.com"    
   },
   {
     "Name"  : "Shop2", 
     "Email" : "shop2@email.com"    
   }    
]
```

Now you post and `object` not an `array`.

Can you show how you serialize your object to `json`? Maby there is a way much easier.